# MYSQL - select row based on condition, otherwise select other row

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, case, mysql-8.0

I have a table **products** which have an association with **product_prices**.
Each product can have multiple prices for different countries.

*Desired outcome:*  When I run the query, I want to receive **all products with 1 single price based on country condition**.

> Logic
>
> 1. If product has price for the specified country-> then country price
>    will be displayed.
> 2. If product does not have price for the specified
>    country-> then price for with country_id 400 needs to be displayed.
> 3. If product has no price for specified country and for country with id 400 -> then the price with country_id 500 needs to be displayed.
> 4. If product has not price for specified country and id 400, and id 500 -> then price which has country with biggest amount of total users will be
>    displayed.

I did something like this for 1 single product. But I don't know how to achieve these for all products.

```
select p.id, pp.price, pp.country_id,
(CASE WHEN (pp.country_id=:countryId) then 0 else
    (CASE WHEN (pp.country_id=400) then 1 else
        (case when (pp.country_id=500) then 2 else 3 END) END) END) as priorityIndex
from products p
inner join product_prices pp on p.id = pp.product_id
inner join countries c on pp.country_id = c.id
where p.id = '00057c218b154d5b838b928a0189ff9f'
order by priorityIndex limit 1;
```

My data:
**Country table**

| country_id | country_code | total_users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | FR | 10 |
| 10 | US | 100 |
| 27 | UK | 200 |
| 400 | EU | 160 |
| 500 | GLOBAL | 150 |

**Product price table**

| product_id | price_id | price | country_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| product1 | 1a | 19.99 | 27 |
| product1 | 1b | 20.99 | 400 |
| product1 | 1c | 30.99 | 500 |
| product2 | 2a | 199.99 | 10 |
| product2 | 2b | 299.99 | 400 |
| product3 | 3a | 50.99 | 500 |
| product4 | 4a | 40 | 2 |
| product4 | 4a | 45 | 10 |

My expected output when inserting country 27:

| product_id | price | country_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| product1 | 19.99 | 27 |
| product2 | 20.99 | 400 |
| product3 | 50.99 | 500 |
| product4 | 45 | 10 |

---

I did something like this. But I am not sure only about the last part. In case product price needs to be choosed based on total dealers.

```
select A.id, A.price_id, A.price, A.country from
(select p.id, pp.id as price_id, pp.price, pp.country_id as country,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY p.id order by (CASE WHEN (pp.country_id=:countryId) then 0 else
            (CASE WHEN (pp.country_id=400) then 1 else
                (case when (pp.country_id=500) then 2 else 3 END) END) END), c.total_dealer_users desc) AS rowNumber
 from products p
          inner join product_prices pp on p.id = pp.product_id
          inner join countries c on pp.country_id = c.id
 where p.id in ('00057c218b154d5b838b928a0189ff9f','054a8caf911e4ff3a594990af20a9611')) as A
where rowNumber=1;
```

Comment: so you probably want to look at the row_number() function  https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-row_number-function.  partition by your product and order by whatever your business logic is. then just pick the rows where rownum = 1

Comment: @BryanDellinger I looked at the documentation and tried something like this:

Comment: select A.id, A.price_id, A.price, A.country, A.rowNumber  from
(select p.id, pp.id as price_id, pp.price, pp.country_id as country, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY p.id) AS rowNumber
 from products p
          inner join product_prices pp on p.id = pp.product_id
          inner join countries c on pp.country_id = c.id order by (CASE WHEN (pp.country_id=:countryId) then 0 else
     (CASE WHEN (pp.country_id=400) then 1 else
         (case when (pp.country_id=500) then 2 else 3 END) END) END)) as A;

Comment: @BryanDellinger but rowNumber did not help me with anything. It does not make partition correctly. I tried to use partition by pp.country_id and also pp.id but still nothing. The rowNumber 1 always does not match with the fields I need to retrieve

Comment: @MatBailie MySQL version - 8.0.26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    pp.product_id,
    pp.price_id,
    pp.price,
    pp.country_id as country,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY pp.product_id
          ORDER BY FIELD(
                     c.country_id,
                     27,
                     400,
                     500,
                     c.country_id
                   ),
                   c.total_users DESC
    )
      AS rowNumber
  FROM
    product_price   pp
  INNER JOIN
    country         c
      ON pp.country_id = c.country_id
)
  AS ranked_price
WHERE
  rowNumber=1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94f8851be7f309d8c4fd1946230d7999

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL 8.0+ `ROW_NUMBER()` allows to drop all rows except first per product:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT p.id, 
        pp.price,
        pp.country_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY FIELD(pp.country_id, 500, 400, 27) DESC) AS `rn`
    FROM products AS p
        JOIN product_prices AS pp
            ON p.id = pp.product_id
    WHERE p.id IN (...)
) AS t WHERE t.rn=1
```